# Currency formatting in Clojurescript

Tags: javascript, localization, clojurescript

In Javascript to do locale based formatting of a currency, you do

```
(550.753).toLocaleString(undefined, {style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'})
// # $550.75 in en-US
```

How do you do the same in Clojurescript?

I've tried

```
(.toLocaleString 550.753 nil {:style "currency" :currency "USD"})
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running your JS sample, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object(…)` because you're passing `null` as a locale. The same error happens in ClojureScript too. [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) requires you pass it a locale.

Fixing this to provide the `de-DE` locale:

JavaScript:

```
(550.753).toLocaleString('de-DE', {style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'})
// "550,75 €"
```

ClojureScript:

```
(.toLocaleString 550.753 "de-DE" #js {:style "currency" :currency "USD"})
;; "550,75 $"
```

`#js` is used to convert a ClojureScript map into a JavaScript Object.

If you want to use the default locale instead, pass either `#js []`, or `js/undefined`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm wondering if there's a way to have an undefined value for locale. In other JS I've written (targeting Firefox), which is intended to be locale agnostic, specifying undefined for the locale means the browser locale is used. Is this possible in Clojurescript?

Comment: `(.toLocaleString 550.753 js/undefined #js {:style "currency" :currency "USD"})` is what I was looking for.

Comment: Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#locales_argument, you would probably be better off passing `[]` if you want to use the default locale.

Answer (score 2):

Since Clojurescript is using Google Closure library extensively, you can leverage it's i18n currency formatting functions

```clj
(import '[goog.i18n NumberFormat]
        '[goog.i18n currency])

(let [fmt (NumberFormat. (.getLocalCurrencyPattern currency "USD"))]
  (.format fmt 123.456)) ;; => "$123,46"
```